# Reading selected items from JSON tree

Tags: jquery, json

This is the structure of my tree:

```
[
    {
        _id: "5981d239b2a86100046ccdb8",
        title: "Første test fra heroku med database: moviestest",
        releaseYear: "2017",
        director: "clbo",
        genre: "Horror"
    },
    {
        _id: "59e460f5cb670a0004c40b1b",
        title: "Hanseman",
        releaseYear: "2011",
        director: "me",
        genre: "Horror"
    },
    {
        _id: "59e46106cb670a0004c40b1c",
        title: "007",
        releaseYear: "2017",
        director: "jon",
        genre: "action"
    }
]
```

I'm using this code to retrieve all the data:

```html
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://myapiurl/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data, status, xhr)
            {
                $("#json").html(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error)
            {
                $("#json").html("Error: " + status + " " + error);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

My code above display everything from the JSON tree. I want to learn how to navigate in the json tree and display particular items or keys.
I want to know in this scenario how can I only fetch the titles from this API?

I've been trying to search of examples but without luck. I have a feeling that that problem might be due to I'm not sure what to search for. What this problem I have called? Is it JSON syntax? or is it on the jQuery part?

Comment: Please put the example JSON as text, someone might want to copy it for testing but now it needs effort that you should make.

Comment: @pirho I changed it now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial query that can be clarified upon learning the basics. Please read through any of the numerous tutorials available on the internet. W3Schools do cover this as well as many other basic operations of parsing a JSON:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp

For this particular case, you need to do something like:

```
var title = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    title[i] = data[i].title;
}
```